# What is the difference in eclipse when starting tests by right clicking on source folder

Tags: eclipse, junit

To test-run integration tests in eclipse I right click on the test und select 'Run as' - 'JUnit Test'.
To run all tests of a package I can right-click on the package name - select 'Run as' etc.

But when right clicking on the source folder, 'src/test/java' in my case, the test seem to execute with a different set of parameters/environment. They execute, but they do not find all required resources.

What is the difference between the execution when running all test of a source folder, compared to running all tests of a package ? 
Or, where can I see the start parameters of the test runs?

Background:
The reason why I'm asking this - when I execute the integration tests with Jenkins/maven I get exactly the same errors as when starting the tests by right clicking on the source, and I cannot find the difference.

Comment: Did you check the Arguments and  Classpath tab in the Run configurations on Eclipse.. you can put params in the Arguments tab if your class is expecting a runtime parameter.